# multiple description coding

Tags: video, encoding, streaming, h.264

How can I encode an h264 video to be MDC (multiple description coding)

Answer (score 2):

## You can't (but...)

It is not possible today to just check a box on existing software, stream video encoded as [h264](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H264) MDC, decode it and play it back in a browser.  There is no h264 MDC profile.  (Without more details of your intent, I am assuming general web-based streaming video.)

Note that MDC is different from '[bitrate peeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitrate_peeling)', which can be found in Real's SureStream.  That is basically packaging multiple, individual streams into a single media file for playback.  The client and server negotiate which stream to send.  This is fundamentally different from MDC.

That said, it's early days for MDC, and it is still largely academic.  There is no standard for it (yet), there is no production full source->encoder->decoder->target path implementation (yet, if ever).

If you want to encode (and obviously stream and then decode) h264 MDC you'll have to jump into the world of academia and probably write it yourself.